# Rails 3 - validation rules and HTML tags in the message

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model, message

> validates_presence_of :city, :message => "City is
>   required item!"

I would like to ask you if is possible to insert some HTML tags into the error message, for example if I would want to have a word "City" bold.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using traditional 'errorExplanation' div in the beginning of the page, you can use something like this:

```
<% @some_entity.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg.html_safe %></li>
<% end %>
```

In the other case, if you're using `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc`, you can past `html_safe` in appropriate place of that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:message => "<b>City</b> is required item!".html_safe`.

Comment: Yea, I tried this one already, but in the browser will be displayed only the tag, the text will be not bold.